# How does armor affect initiative?

Tags: dnd-5e, initiative

I just couldn't find simply answer to my question: When my characters is wearing heavy armor like chain mail, can he still get modifier to initiative from DEX or not?

I'm not sure wearing heavy armors have influence on all test based on DEX including initiative or without initiative.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

## Armor doesn't generally affect Dexterity checks.

There's no general rule that says that wearing armor affects all Dexterity checks that a character makes, and initiative rolls are a Dexterity check.

There is a specific rule about armor and Dexterity (Stealth) checks (["Armor and Shields"](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/basic-rules/equipment#ArmorandShields)):

> If the Armor table shows "Disadvantage" in the Stealth column, the wearer has disadvantage on Dexterity (Stealth) checks.

All [heavy armor](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/basic-rules/equipment#HeavyArmor) has this property.